# Why do I sometimes get +5 points on upvotes and other times I get +10?

Tags: discussion, up-votes

When I get and upvote sometimes it adds 5 points and other times it adds 10 points. Why does this change?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the [Help Center on Reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation):

> **You gain reputation when:**
>
> - question is voted up: +5
> - answer is voted up: +10
> - answer is marked “accepted”: +15 (+2 to acceptor)
> - suggested edit is accepted: +2 (up to +1000 total per user)
> - bounty awarded to your answer: + full bounty amount
> - one of your answers is awarded a bounty automatically: + half of the bounty amount
> - site association bonus: +100 on each site (awarded a maximum of one time per site)

So you've been getting upvotes on questions (5 pts) and answers (10 pts), that's all.

Answer (score 3):

See the help pages on [reputation](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) and [voting up](https://physics.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). In summary, upvotes on your *questions* get you 5 points, while upvotes on *answers* get you 10. If your answer is accepted you get 15. This is the case across the network.